# Android activity crashes when resuming

Tags: android

My app has a button to open a webpage, however when returning to the app it crashes, I am using onPause() and onRestart() methods. Anyone know why it crashes when resuming to the app after closing the webpage?

```
private void goToUrl(String url) {
    Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(url);

    Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);

    startActivity(launchBrowser);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    titleMusic.release();
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();

    titleMusic.start();
}
```

logCat stack trace

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity java.lang.IllegalStateException
04-23 15:49:09.886: E/AndroidRuntime(18310):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2836)
04-23 15:49:09.886: E/AndroidRuntime(18310):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2865)
04-23 15:49:09.886: E/AndroidRuntime(18310):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1288)
04-23 15:49:09.886: E/AndroidRuntime(18310):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-23 15:49:09.886: E/AndroidRuntime(18310):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
04-23 15:49:09.886: E/AndroidRuntime(18310):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
04-23 15:49:09.886: E/AndroidRuntime(18310):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-23 15:49:09.886: E/AndroidRuntime(18310):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-23 15:49:09.886: E/AndroidRuntime(18310):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
04-23 15:49:09.886: E/AndroidRuntime(18310):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
04-23 15:49:09.886: E/AndroidRuntime(18310):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-23 15:49:09.886: E/AndroidRuntime(18310): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
04-23 15:49:09.886: E/AndroidRuntime(18310):    at android.media.MediaPlayer._start(Native Method)
04-23 15:49:09.886: E/AndroidRuntime(18310):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.start(MediaPlayer.java:1097)
04-23 15:49:09.886: E/AndroidRuntime(18310):    at com.example.hunglikeanandroid.TitleScreen.onRestart(TitleScreen.java:364)
04-23 15:49:09.886: E/AndroidRuntime(18310):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestart(Instrumentation.java:1181)
04-23 15:49:09.886: E/AndroidRuntime(18310):    at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:5291)
04-23 15:49:09.886: E/AndroidRuntime(18310):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5302)
04-23 15:49:09.886: E/AndroidRuntime(18310):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2826)
```

Comment: `titleMusic=null` May be

Comment: maybe better use onResume instead onRestart

Comment: @PiotrGolinski that's probably answer-worthy.  The real problem as you allude to, is that onRestart() does not correspond to onPause() but rather to onStop() and may therefore not be invoked if the activity is only paused and not stopped.  As you point out, the actions taken in onPause() should be counteracted by those in an onResume().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
04-23 15:49:09.886: E/AndroidRuntime(18310): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException 
04-23 15:49:09.886: E/AndroidRuntime(18310): at android.media.MediaPlayer._start(Native Method)
```

This exception indicates that your media player is in a "wrong" state. Being a state machine, it must be properly [initialised](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html), make sure that you properly deal with it's state when going out/coming back to the activity.

For example, in your onPause(), you're releasing MediaPlayer resources, so when you're back, it's not initialised again.